# Can I change the content license on my Stackoverflow/Stackexchange posts to something more permissive like MIT?

Tags: mit, license, copyleft, cc-by-sa, api

I was experimenting with Stackoverflow's API requests and I noticed this on my posts:
[image]

I've mentioned in previous posts that while I respect CC BY-SA 4.0's intentions, I don't like the copyleft implications of CC BY-SA 4.0. I prefer a more permissive license such as MIT. Can I make my posts MIT licensed?

Is there some way to "opt in" to MIT license instead of CC BY-SA 4.0?

Comment: You can dual license _your_ content, but you must license it under CC BY-SA; that is part of the T&Cs you agreed to when you signed up. If you don't like that, your only option is not to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It's also possible to use Stack Overflow without posting any code there (i.e. don't provide Answers that contain any code). Technically you might be able to get away with posting the code off-site (on a different platform) and then saying in the Answer that you can only link to the code and cannot reproduce it in the Answer itself due to licensing restrictions of the code snippets in question. Of course, if people realize you're doing this to circumvent the SO rules/policies, probably it's going to attract moderator attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Phillip Kendall mentioned, you can release your content under multiple licenses, as long as one of those licenses is the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license. The best place to state this is probably in your profile description. You may not need to necessarily mention the CC-BY-SA, as Stack Exchange's policy automatically releases all contributions under that license. [The user MultiplyByZero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2688027/multiplybyzer0) provides an example of this, with code contributions being released under the Unlicense and text contributions under the Creative Commons Zero.

So you can state in your profile description that you release your posts under a different license or licenses, and others can understand that they can use your posts under either the license(s) you specified or the CC-BY-SA.